# Getting a 403 error while trying to activate a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting a 403 error while activating a plugin in WordPress. The link to the error is http://socialsavvy.in/wp-admin/themes.php?page=install-required-plugins&plugin=wpfw_menus_management&plugin_name=WPFW+-+Menus+Management&plugin_source=http%3A%2F%2Fseowptheme.com%2Fthemeinstaller%2Fplugins%2Fwpfw_menus_management.1.5.zip&tgmpa-activate=activate-plugin&tgmpa-activate-nonce=c396ac285f

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission of your file, fix them to 755.

You could also try to redownload and reinstall the plugin, make sure to download it from a safe source, if you are trying to install a nulled plugin, forget it and buy it.

This error is very strange, but it could only be permission or bug in the current script.

Comment: Which file should I edit to 755 tried downloading again doesn't work